# Dynamic measure text in a a custom listview item, OnGlobalLayoutListener only called once

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-adapter

I am showing a ListView in my app with a custom item. The custom item is already doing quite a bit of work since I am using the *android-swipelistview* from 47deg found [here](https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview).

So the "front" part of the list item is a LinearLayout with various bits nested inside it - icons on left and right and in the middle 3 different TextViews - name, address and notes. Each TextView has a different text size but the height of the whole list item is fixed so that the list looks fairly uniform,

The middle item - the address - has been causing me a bit of trouble. Basically I want to make sure it fits in and looks good. I have set space enough for it to be able to take up 2 lines, then ellipsize it after that. However if the address is very short then it all fits in one line and I have a rather large space before notes line which looks bad.

So I thought I would do some analysis on the text - if it is shorter than one line I will break it after the last comma (my addresses always have commas) so I fill both lines.

I have some code like this in my Adapter

```
private class MyViewHolder {
    ImageView defaultLogo;
    TextView name;
    TextView address;
    TextView notes;
    ImageView otherLogo;
}
.
.
.
    @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    MyViewHolder holder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        .
        .
        holder = new MyViewHolder();
        .
        .
        .
        holder.address = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.street_address);
        .
        .
        .
    else {
        holder = (MyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    .
    .
    .
    MyItem item = (MyItem) getItem(position);

    // Set address:
    doAfterLayout(holder.address, fixLines);
    holder.address.setText(item.getAddress());
    .
    .
    .
}
.
.
.
/**
 * Runs a piece of code after the layout run
 */
public static void doAfterLayout(final View view, final FixLinesRunnable runnable) {
    final OnGlobalLayoutListener listener = new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            runnable.view = view;
            runnable.run();
        }
    };
    view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener);
}

private class FixLinesRunnable implements Runnable {
    public View view;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // try to get the width of this control and the text
        TextView tv = (TextView) view;
        int lineCount = tv.getLineCount();
        if (0 == lineCount) {
            return;FixLinesRunnable
        } else if (1 < lineCount) {
            //lineCount over 2 means we leave text as it is
            return;
        }
        //if we got here we have only one line text
        //want to try to force it to be 2 lines by breaking at last comma
        String text = tv.getText().toString();
        int lastCommaPos = text.lastIndexOf(", ");
        if (lastCommaPos > text.length() - 1) {
            //comma is right at the end
            lastCommaPos = text.lastIndexOf(", ",lastCommaPos);
        }
        if (0 < lastCommaPos) {
            String secondLine = text.substring(lastCommaPos + 2);
            text = text.substring(0, lastCommaPos + 1) + "\n" + secondLine;
        }
        tv.setText(text);
    }
```

This Really, Nearly works. It works fine the first time the list is shown - Addresses which are too short are pushed into 2 lines, broken on the last comma. But if I scroll the item out of view and back into view it doesn't work...what could be going wrong?

The original doAfterLayout function would remove the OnGlobalLayoutListener after the first adjustment, but even with the OnGlobalLayoutListener still there, it doesn't get called a second time when the item reappears, so the text shows in one line?

Anyone got any ideas?

EDIT: Annoyingly, if something covers up the list (I have another window which pulls open from the side and covers some items) the visible items redraw... I can even see it before they are covered...

Comment: One thing that comes to mind is that each time you call "getView", you are calling "doAfterLayout" which means every time you are adding a new listener.   That should happen only once.  Try to fix that and see if that causes an issue.

Comment: Thanks @DanielBenedykt, On your advice I thought it might be a good idea to subclass the textedit. I override onSizeChanged and I get the same behaviour as before - works once but if the view scrolls off and back it looks wrong...what other function is called when the view comes back into view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Daniel-Benedykt for pointing me in the right direction.

In the end I subclassed TextView. The only place I found I could override which would work each time the view was shown was onDraw...so:

```
public class AddressTextView extends TextView {

public AddressTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw (Canvas canvas) {
    int lineCount = getLineCount();
    if (0 == lineCount) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        return;
    } else if (1 < lineCount) {
        //lineCount over 2 means we leave text as it is
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        return;
    }
    //if we got here we have only one line text
    //want to try to force it to be 2 lines by breaking at last comma
    String text = getText().toString();
    int lastCommaPos = text.lastIndexOf(", ");
    if (lastCommaPos > text.length() - 1) {
        //comma is right at the end
        lastCommaPos = text.lastIndexOf(", ",lastCommaPos);
    }
    if (0 < lastCommaPos) {
        String secondLine = text.substring(lastCommaPos + 2);
        text = text.substring(0, lastCommaPos + 1) + "\n" + secondLine;
    }
    setText(text);

    super.onDraw(canvas);
}


}
```

Hope this helps someone.